# AS3 - getting symbols from an assets library WITHOUT Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, embed, symbols

Been searching around for a long time, and the only examples I can find for doing this are something like this:

```
[Embed(source="Assets.swf", symbol="dog")]
private static var _Dog:Class;

public static function get Dog():MovieClip {
      return new _Dog();
}
```

But this seems to be flex-only (I get the error "unable to resolve 'Assets.swf' for transcoding")
How do you do this in plain AS3?

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally use the CASALib util called [SwfLoad](http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_load_SwfLoad.html).

In order to do this, you need to make sure you export the movie clip for ActionScript. Also, if you're movie clip classes are in packages you need to enter the fully qualified name (com.example.MyClassName) into the createClassByName function of SwfLoad.

Hope that helps!